# Is refactoring with a separate function possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a table component where many of the table columns are handled similarly.
Is there any way to optimize this code, maybe in a separate function?

```
import useTableStyles from 'admin/components/table/AdminTable.styles';
import useStyles from 'portal/pages/wasOperators/views/ViewEditOperators.style';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Form } from 'shared/components/Form';
import WssoService from 'shared/services/WssoService';

import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { Button, Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';

interface Props {
  isEditing?: boolean;
}

const BenchmarkingTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ isEditing }) => {
  const tableClasses = useTableStyles();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { operatorsId }: any = useParams();

  const valuesForInverseCalculation = [
    'continuityWaterSupply',
    'totalLossesWaterSupplySystems',
    'pressureWaterSupplySystem',
    'sewerNetworkAccidents',
    'floodsThirdPartyCausedBySewage',
  ];

  const benchmarkingDetailsInit = {
    levelWaterSupplyServices: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    qualityDrinkWaterLargeAreas: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    qualityDrinkWaterSmallAreas: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    monitorQualityDrinkWater: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    continuityWaterSupply: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    totalLossesWaterSupplySystems: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    pressureWaterSupplySystem: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    levelCoverageServiceDisposalOfWastewater: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    levelCoverageServiceTreatmentOfWastewater: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    wastewaterQuality: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    sewerNetworkAccidents: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
    floodsThirdPartyCausedBySewage: {
      target: '',
      result: '',
      status: '',
    },
  };
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>(benchmarkingDetailsInit);
  const [KEY, setKEY] = useState<any>(new Date());

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result: any = await WssoService.getBenchmarking(
        operatorsId,
        KEY.getFullYear()
      );
      if (result && result.data && result.data.json) {
        setData(JSON.parse(result.data.json));
      } else {
        setData(null);
      }
    })();
    /* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
  }, [KEY, operatorsId]);

  const HandleKEYChange = () => {
    return (
      <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
        <DatePicker
          variant="inline"
          inputVariant="outlined"
          format={'yyyy'}
          views={['year']}
          onChange={setKEY}
          value={KEY}
        />
      </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    );
  };

  const updateBenchmarking = async (editValues: any) => {
    const request = {
      json: JSON.stringify(editValues),
    };
    const result: any = await WssoService.editAddBenchmarking(
      operatorsId,
      KEY.getFullYear(),
      request
    );
    if (result && result.data && result.json) {
      setData(JSON.parse(result.data.json));
    }
  };

  const onUpdateSuccess = () => {
    toast.success(t('itemUpdateSuccessfully'));
  };

  const handleSaveData = async () => {
    if (data) {
      await updateBenchmarking(data);
      onUpdateSuccess();
    }
  };

  const handleOnTextChange = (
    key: string,
    valueKey: string,
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
  ) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    const newData = Object.assign({}, data, {
      [key]: Object.assign({}, data[key], {
        [valueKey]: value,
      }),
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  const handleColorChange = (name: any, target: any, result: any) => {
    const removePercentFromTarget = target.includes('%')
      ? target.slice(0, -1)
      : target;

    const convertedTarget = Number(removePercentFromTarget);

    const removePercentFromResult = result.includes('%')
      ? result.slice(0, -1)
      : result;

    const convertedResult = Number(removePercentFromResult);

    target = convertedTarget;
    result = convertedResult;

    let final: any;

    const arrOfNames = [];
    arrOfNames.push(name);

    if (arrOfNames.some(x => valuesForInverseCalculation.includes(x))) {
      if (target < result) {
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (final = data[k].status = 'red');
        });
      } else if (target > result) {
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (final = data[k].status = 'green');
        });
      } else if (target === result) {
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (final = data[k].status = 'yellow');
        });
      }
    } else {
      if (target > result) {
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (final = data[k].status = 'red');
        });
      } else if (target < result || (target === result && result === 100)) {
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (final = data[k].status = 'green');
        });
      } else if (target === result) {
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (final = data[k].status = 'yellow');
        });
      }
    }

    return final;
  };

  const updateData = (newData: any[]) => {
    setData(newData);
  };

  const renderBenchmarkDetails = () => {
    if (isEditing) {
      return data ? (
        Object.keys(data).map(k => {
          return (
            <tr>
              <td>{t(k)}</td>
              <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
                <TextField
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e: any) => handleOnTextChange(k, 'target', e)}
                  value={data[k].target}
                  inputProps={{ min: 0, style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
                  required
                />
              </td>
              <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
                <TextField
                  type="text"
                  onChange={(e: any) => handleOnTextChange(k, 'result', e)}
                  value={data[k].result}
                  inputProps={{ min: 0, style: { textAlign: 'center' } }}
                  required
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <tr>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    } else {
      return data ? (
        Object.keys(data).map((rowName, i) => {
          return (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{t(rowName)}</td>
              <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
                {data[rowName].target}
              </td>
              <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
                {data[rowName].result}
              </td>
              <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
                <div
                  style={{
                    width: '15px',
                    height: '15px',
                    borderRadius: '50%',
                    backgroundColor: handleColorChange(
                      rowName,
                      data[rowName].target,
                      data[rowName].result
                    ),
                  }}
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          );
        })
      ) : (
        <tr>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
          <td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  };

  const handleExport = useCallback(async () => {
    const dataRows: any = [];

    if (data) {
      Object.keys(data).map(rowName => {
        dataRows.push([t(rowName), data[rowName].target, data[rowName].result]);
        return null;
      });
    }

    let dataToCSV: any[][] = [];

    if (dataRows && dataRows.length > 0) {
      dataToCSV = [[t('criteria'), t('targets'), t('results')], ...dataRows];

      const csvContent: string =
        'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF' +
        dataToCSV
          .map(e =>
            e
              .map(r =>
                r instanceof Array
                  ? `"${(r ?? '').toString().replace(',', ', ')}"`
                  : (r ?? '').toString().replace(',', ' ')
              )
              .join(',')
          )
          .join('\n');

      const encodedUri: string = encodeURI(csvContent);

      const link: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement('a');
      link.setAttribute('href', encodedUri);
      link.setAttribute('download', `${t('exportedTableData')}.csv`);

      link.click();
    }
  }, [data, t]);
console.log(operatorsId);
console.log(benchmarkingDetailsInit);
console.log(updateBenchmarking);
  return (
    <Grid>
      <Form
        onSubmit={(formData, { resetForm }) => {
          const tempData = !!operatorsId
            ? {
                ...formData,
              }
            : {
                ...formData,
                ...(!!operatorsId && {
                  operatorsAreaEntity: {
                    id: parseInt(operatorsId, 0),
                  },
                }),
                id: operatorsId ? undefined : Date.now(),
              };
          updateData([tempData, ...data]);
          resetForm();
        }}
        initialValues={benchmarkingDetailsInit}
        enableReinitialize={true}
      >
        <div className={classes.tableContainer}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.containerLegendBench}>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: 'flex',
                  justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                }}
              >
                <div className={classes.yearBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  <HandleKEYChange />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.legendBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  {t('reachedResult')}
                  <div
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: '3px',
                      width: '11px',
                      height: '9px',
                      borderRadius: '50%',
                      backgroundColor: '#006400',
                      display: 'inline-block',
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.legendBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  {t('almostReachedResult')}
                  <div
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: '3px',
                      width: '11px',
                      height: '9px',
                      borderRadius: '50%',
                      backgroundColor: '#FFDF00',
                      display: 'inline-block',
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.legendBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  {t('notReachedResult')}
                  <tr
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: '3px',
                      width: '11px',
                      height: '9px',
                      borderRadius: '50%',
                      backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
                      display: 'inline-block',
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <table className={tableClasses.table}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>{t('criteria')}</th>
                <th>{t('targets')}</th>
                <th>{t('results')}</th>
                <th />
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{renderBenchmarkDetails()}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Button
            style={{ margin: '5px 0px 10px 10px' }}
            type="button"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleExport}
            disabled={!data}
          >
            {t('export')}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        {isEditing && (
          <Button onClick={handleSaveData} className={classes.submitButton}>
            {t('save')} <i className={`fas fa-save ${classes.submitIcon}`} />
          </Button>
        )}
      </Form>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default BenchmarkingTable;
```

Comment: What code are you referring to? I can only see two images. Please may you add the code as text to the question as a [mcve]?

Comment: atleast provide the text version of the images

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-mcclintock-22qze?file=/src/App.js

Comment: the entire code only from this file - from the codesandbox, sorry, i am new here :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here's how to get more help. 1. Edit your question and paste the relevant code _as text in a code block_. Then we can copy and paste that code as we create your answer. 2. Describe your problem a bit more. It's not clear right now what "refactoring with a separate function means".

Comment: Oh my gosh, so much `any`!  So much redundancy!  I can definitely help you here because I love fixing bad code.  Want to watch me do it live? https://codesandbox.io/live/yhvekw4

Answer (score 0):

You've got 60 lines of code just to initialize an empty object!  It seems like each key of this object is a row of your table and each value shares the same format:

```
interface Benchmark {
  target: string;
  result: string;
  status: string;
}
```

So the `data` can be described as `Record<string, Benchmark>`.  Though it might make more sense to make the `name` be a property and let `data` be an `array`.

Your condition with the  `<td>{t('noDetailsToDisplay')}</td>` will never be hit because you've initialized `data` to your empty object so `data` is always `true`.

If you want to show something different when there is not data then you should do any one of these:

1. Use an `undefined` initial state.
2. Have a separate `isLoading` state that you set with your `useEffect` hooks.
3. Check `Object.keys(data).length > 0` instead of checking `!! data`.

---

Another part of your code that seems majorly illogical is the `handleColorChange` function.  Despite the misleading name, it seems like this function is designed to compute a color string based on the `result` and `target` values.  This color is the `status` property and you mutate state to get it there.  Instead you should compute the color and add it as `status` after you fetch the data and before you set it to state.

---

If you want a row with 4 empty cells, you can do this:

```
<tr>
  {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, i) => (
    <td key={i}>{t("noDetailsToDisplay")}</td>
  ))}
</tr>
```

You have that same JSX block in two places so you want to fix that.

---

I haven't fixed everything, but I have fixed quite a lot.

```
import useTableStyles from 'admin/components/table/AdminTable.styles';
import useStyles from 'portal/pages/wasOperators/views/ViewEditOperators.style';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Form } from 'shared/components/Form';
import WssoService from 'shared/services/WssoService';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { Button, Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { DatePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from '@material-ui/pickers';


interface BenchmarkFromService {
  target: string;
  result: string;
}

interface BenchmarkRow extends BenchmarkFromService {
  name: string;
  status: string;
}

const BenchmarkingTable: React.FC<Props> = ({ isEditing }) => {
  const tableClasses = useTableStyles();
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { operatorsId } = useParams<{ operatorsId: string }>();

  /**
   * each row of the table is a Benchmark
   */
  const [data, setData] = useState<BenchmarkRow[]>([]);
  const [KEY, setKEY] = useState(new Date());

  // extract shared logic from "get" and "update" responses
  // memoized so it's safe as a useEffect dependency
  const handleResult = useCallback(
    // is this really any?  what is it when it's not { data: { json: string } }
    (result: any) => {
      /**
       * regular colors and inverted colors have the same logic, just swap the target and result
       */
      const computeColor = (a: number, b: number): string => {
        if (a > b) {
          return "red";
        } else if (a < b || (a === b && b === 100)) {
          return "green";
        } else if (a === b) {
          return "yellow";
        }
      };

      const valuesForInverseCalculation = [
        "continuityWaterSupply",
        "totalLossesWaterSupplySystems",
        "pressureWaterSupplySystem",
        "sewerNetworkAccidents",
        "floodsThirdPartyCausedBySewage"
      ];

      const toNum = (value: string): number =>
        parseFloat(value.replace("%", ""));

      try {
        const raw: Record<string, BenchmarkFromService> = JSON.parse(
          result.data.json
        );
        const formatted = Object.entries(raw).map(
          ([name, { target, result }]) => ({
            name,
            target,
            result,
            status: valuesForInverseCalculation.includes(name)
              ? computeColor(toNum(result), toNum(target))
              : computeColor(toNum(target), toNum(result))
          })
        );
        setData(formatted);
      } catch (e) {
        // catch errors from malformatted response or unparsable JSON
        setData([]);
      }
    },
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result: any = await WssoService.getBenchmarking(
        operatorsId,
        KEY.getFullYear()
      );
      handleResult(result);
    })();
  }, [KEY, operatorsId, handleResult]);

  const updateBenchmarking = async (editValues: any) => {
    const request = {
      json: JSON.stringify(editValues)
    };
    const result: any = await WssoService.editAddBenchmarking(
      operatorsId,
      KEY.getFullYear(),
      request
    );
    handleResult(result);
  };

  const onUpdateSuccess = () => {
    toast.success(t("itemUpdateSuccessfully"));
  };

  const handleSaveData = async () => {
    if (data) {
      await updateBenchmarking(data);
      onUpdateSuccess();
    }
  };

  const renderCell = (property: keyof BenchmarkRow, row: BenchmarkRow) => {
    const onChange = (
      e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement>
    ) => {
      setData((previous) =>
        previous.map((obj) =>
          obj.name === row.name
            ? {
                ...obj,
                [property]: e.target.value
              }
            : obj
        )
      );
    };

    return (
      <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
        {isEditing ? (
          <TextField
            type="text"
            onChange={onChange}
            value={row[property]}
            inputProps={{ min: 0, style: { textAlign: "center" } }}
            required
          />
        ) : (
          row[property]
        )}
      </td>
    );
  };

  const renderBenchmarkDetails = () => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      return (
        <tr>
          {Array.from({ length: 4 }).map((_, i) => (
            <td key={i}>{t("noDetailsToDisplay")}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      );
    }
    return data.map((row) => (
      <tr key={row.name}>
        <th scope="row">{row.name}</th>
        {renderCell("target", row)}
        {renderCell("result", row)}
        <td className={classes.benchTextfieldAlign}>
          <div
            style={{
              width: "15px",
              height: "15px",
              borderRadius: "50%",
              backgroundColor: row.status
            }}
          />
        </td>
      </tr>
    ));
  };

  const handleExport = useCallback(async () => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const dataRows = data.map((row) => [t(row.name), row.target, row.result]);
    const dataToCSV = [
      [t("criteria"), t("targets"), t("results")],
      ...dataRows
    ];

    const csvContent: string =
      "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,\uFEFF" +
      dataToCSV
        .map((row) =>
          row
            .map(
              (cell) => cell.replace(",", "\\,") // I think it's ok to escape the comma like this?
            )
            .join(",")
        )
        .join("\n");

    const encodedUri: string = encodeURI(csvContent);

    const link: HTMLAnchorElement = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", `${t("exportedTableData")}.csv`);

    link.click();
  }, [data, t]);

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Form
        onSubmit={(formData, { resetForm }) => {
          const tempData = !!operatorsId
            ? {
                ...formData
              }
            : {
                ...formData,
                ...(!!operatorsId && {
                  operatorsAreaEntity: {
                    id: parseInt(operatorsId, 0)
                  }
                }),
                id: operatorsId ? undefined : Date.now()
              };
          setData([tempData, ...data]);
          resetForm();
        }}
        initialValues={{}}
        enableReinitialize={true}
      >
        <div className={classes.tableContainer}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div className={classes.containerLegendBench}>
              <div
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "flex-end"
                }}
              >
                <div className={classes.yearBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                    <DatePicker
                      variant="inline"
                      inputVariant="outlined"
                      format={"yyyy"}
                      views={["year"]}
                      onChange={setKEY}
                      value={KEY}
                    />
                  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
                </div>
                <div className={classes.legendBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  {t("reachedResult")}
                  <div
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: "3px",
                      width: "11px",
                      height: "9px",
                      borderRadius: "50%",
                      backgroundColor: "#006400",
                      display: "inline-block"
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.legendBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  {t("almostReachedResult")}
                  <div
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: "3px",
                      width: "11px",
                      height: "9px",
                      borderRadius: "50%",
                      backgroundColor: "#FFDF00",
                      display: "inline-block"
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
                <div className={classes.legendBoxBenchmarketType}>
                  {t("notReachedResult")}
                  <tr
                    style={{
                      marginLeft: "3px",
                      width: "11px",
                      height: "9px",
                      borderRadius: "50%",
                      backgroundColor: "#FF0000",
                      display: "inline-block"
                    }}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Grid>
          <table className={tableClasses.table}>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>{t("criteria")}</th>
                <th>{t("targets")}</th>
                <th>{t("results")}</th>
                <th />
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{renderBenchmarkDetails()}</tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Button
            style={{ margin: "5px 0px 10px 10px" }}
            type="button"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={handleExport}
            disabled={!data}
          >
            {t("export")}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        {isEditing && (
          <Button onClick={handleSaveData} className={classes.submitButton}>
            {t("save")} <i className={`fas fa-save ${classes.submitIcon}`} />
          </Button>
        )}
      </Form>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default BenchmarkingTable;
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Linda, that is really helpful! :)